# How to call GsonRequest multiple times/ in loop

Tags: android, json, android-volley

In my application i want to fetch data from multiple URLs and bind `json response` to respective classes, Like `Gallery Url` response will be bind with `Gallery class`.

I am able to make a call for single `URL` and `Class`, But i want to make a call for 10 times with different URLs and Class names. How can i do that?

here is my code:

```
String url="http://icetea09.com/blog-files/demo_json";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tvResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvResult);
    VolleyHelper.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(gsonRequest);
}

final GsonRequest gsonRequest = new GsonRequest(url, Gallery.class, null, new Response.Listener<Gallery>() {

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Gallery gallery) {
        String textResult = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < gallery.matches.size(); i++) {
            Match Item = gallery.matches.get(i);
            textResult += "URL: " + Item.url + "\n";
        }
        tvResult.setText(textResult);
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
        if (volleyError != null) {
            Log.e("MainActivity", "" + volleyError.getMessage());
        }
    }
});
```

Please suggest me how can i make this call in for loop?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way of doing it:

```
private List<String> urls;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    addUrls();
    doRequests();

    tvResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvResult);
    VolleyHelper.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(gsonRequest);
}

private void addUrls() {
    urls = new ArrayList<String> ();
    // add your urls here
    urls.add("http://icetea09.com/blog-files/demo_json");
}

private void doRequests() {
    for (String url : urls) {
        GsonRequest gsonRequest = new GsonRequest(url, Gallery.class, null, new Response.Listener<Gallery>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Gallery gallery) {
            String textResult = "";

            for (int i = 0; i < gallery.matches.size(); i++) {
                Match Item = gallery.matches.get(i);
                textResult += "URL: " + Item.url + "\n";
            }
            tvResult.setText(textResult);
        }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                if (volleyError != null) {
                    Log.e("MainActivity", "" + volleyError.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Feel free to optimize it as you want, as I'm not very familiar with Gson and initializing a new GsonRequest object per iteration is not recommendable for a big ammount of urls.

The idea behing this code is to encapsulate your GsonRequest inside a for loop. All your urls are given inside an ArrayList (add them in the **addUrls()** method!), and a new request is performed for every element in the Array.

To perform this loop with multiple classes, you should create a supper-class and make inherit all your classes from it, and in the loop call this supper-class.

Comment: i want to pass different classes also..so how can i pass them?

Comment: One way of doing it is creating an abstract class and make all your classes inherit from this one.
By the way, what do you want to do exactly?

Comment: I want to fetch data from multiple Urls on Splash Screen and show it on DashBoard Activity

Comment: So do i need to create base class?